# Winmain Cant Display Message in Autostart

Tags: winapi, startup, messagebox, winmain

I have a win32 program, when run manually, it display a message in WinMain, but when I put the same program under registry (Run) so that when the PC reboots, it will run automatically, the message will never appear (but the program run normally).

Anyone knows why there is a difference between starting the program manually (by clicking the exe file) and automatically (via Windows Registry)?

Thanks

Clement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably too soon to display a message at the top of WinMain because you don't have a window yet. Can you wait until you receive your first `WM_CREATE` message?

Comment: Yes, problem solved. It is silly that the path I put in the registry is another program!